# How to add a repo folder to its parent folder's repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

A folder `predis` in my repository, is itself a git repository. I'm having trouble adding it to my repo (without its .git folder).

When I do `git add predis`, nothing happens. Similarly, when I do `git status` it does not show up.

How can I add the `/predis` folder, when it itself is a git repository (from someone else's repo)?

also, while looking into this, i noticed that `git status --ignored` doesn't work, which would have been nice to analyze this. `git add -f predis` does not work either.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Look into submodules.

Comment: @zerkms i would like to add the `predis` folder to my repo, when it seems to be automatically excluding/ignoring it for some reason.

Comment: So remove nested `.git` directory and add it as usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @meagar said about submodules may be what you need. Issue the command:

`git submodule add git:<url for submodule> path/to/save`.

The git-scm book has further details: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules